# Eclipse JBoss deploy loads an old version of the project

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I have a web project that I'm running on jboss server, but whenever I modify something and do `mvn clean install` and restart the server, or even just shut it down and then start it again, it seems not to see the changes and keeps loading the first version of the project. For example if I modify an html file and change the text and then run the install, then if I restart the server it doesn't load the changes.

I've checked my configurations against the correct ones I've found in some answers but they were ok. These are my server configs:

[image]

Also, I've read that starting the server in debug mode would just require a clean install of the project to republish the changes, but that doesn't work either. Are there more settings to change?

Answer (score 0):

eclipse is sometimes sketchy with updating the deployed application on to your jboss. 
try the following:

1. right clicking your application server, press clean.
2. then right click again and press publish.
3. start the server